# Node reference list based on node filtered by group membership

Tags: 7, views, organic-groups, nodes

I have a content type called, "Class Templates" that needs to be able to reference one or more nodes of its own type as a prerequisite list for the classes.
The catch is that I'm using the Organic Groups module to divide up the users into clubs; each club admin will create their own class templates for their clubs use only.

I need to show, to the club admin, only the class templates that are associated to their own club/group, and not all class templates as it is currently happening.

I'm assuming I need a reference view to do this, but I'm buggered if I can figure out how I need to configure it.

**UPDATE:** I've figured out how to do it via hook_form_alter() and it's just as easy as I'm writing modules as is.  I'm still interested in a way to do this via views/references but I'm working on a timeline so I'll have to push ahead this way for now.

Comment: Which module are you using to do references? The older references modules does indeed support using Views, the newer entity_reference does not, as far as I know.

Comment: It's the references module itself - I'm using a reference view for filtering the list of a user's children (another content type), but this case has the benefit of being able to have a contextual reference to the user.